# Why am I not albe to find the NFS shared location on Ubuntu client machines from Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, nginx

I have followed [this](https://www.fosslinux.com/16259/how-to-install-nfs-server-and-client-on-ubuntu.htm#:%7E:text=Ubuntu%20Installing%20NFS%201%20Before%20starting%20the%20installation,server%20package%20using%20the%20following%20command.%20See%20More.) link to configure NFS on Ubuntu 20,

But when I am trying to use my windows machine to access the server IP in the format `//server_IP/`, I am getting error

> Windows cannot find `server_IP`. Make sure to type the name correctly.

I am not sure how to rectify the issue.

NOTE: I have used `nginx` to host the shared location and I am able to see the shared location in browser through the server IP.

Please suggest, Thank you

Comment: Do you have an NFS client for your windows machine?   Does `//server_ip/` even work for NFS, or is that just for SMB (aka Samba aka "windows file share").

Comment: The link which  I have followed talks only about Linux environment(server and client). So, I am not sure how to integrate Linux and windows. Can you please share some link that I can follow and perform the task. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you set up the NFS server and what nginx has to do with it. Is it even possible to have Windows see NFS drives? Did you perhaps mean to set up SMB as cas suggested?

Comment: Sorry, I know very little about windows, I never use it.  A quick google told me that the NFS client is only available for Win 10 Pro and Win 10 Enterprise, but that was from 2016 and may be out of date.  Maybe try over on https://superuser.com/ and/or google for "windows nfs client"

Comment: I think I will have to configure the SMB server for my use case. That is the solution that I came up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default file sharing protocol of Windows is not NFS but SMB. When you type `\\hostname-or-IP\share_name` to Windows Explorer, you're asking Windows to make a connection to the specified SMB file (or printer) share on the specified host.

Windows 10 can use NFS... *if* you install the *optional* Services for NFS add-on, which may only be available to Enterprise and Pro versions of Windows 10.

And even if you install that, unless both systems are joined in a single AD domain, there is no  way for the Linux NFS server to identify Windows users, so there will be no way to specify that one Windows user may access something on the NFS share while another may not; it will be essentially all-or-nothing.

Although configuring Windows is off topic for Unix&Linux SE, here's a link describing how to configure Windows 10 as a basic NFS client:
https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/

Note that the procedure includes registry editing and so is not very user friendly.

Instead, I would recommend installing the Samba software package to your Ubuntu server and using it to share the disk location using Windows' native SMB protocol.

**However, there is a complication:** since Microsoft is deprecating SMB protocol version 1 (SMBv1 for short) and with it the NetBIOS functionality, the parts of the SMB protocol that allow browsing of the network shares (i.e. connecting with just `\\hostname-or-ip\` and seeing what is available on that host) in a non-Active Directory environment are getting disabled and eventually removed.

(Re-enabling SMBv1 is still possible, but **very much not recommended** since the inherent flaws of SMBv1 are what allowed the WannaCry ransom worm to spread so rapidly worldwide in 2017. The specific hole used by the original worm was patched out, but there may be other variations of the same technique still possible, as SMBv1 was/is very complex and SMBv2 was a radical simplification and optimization of the protocol.)

To work around this, Microsoft has introduced a new protocol for announcing & discovering network shares in non-AD environments. This protocol has not been integrated with Samba as yet, but [a separate wsdd2 daemon can read your Samba configuration and provide the necessary announcements](https://github.com/Andy2244/wsdd2) to allow non-Active Directory Windows systems to find your Samba server and see which shares it has available.

The new browsing protocol is called WS-Discover and it also has some security concerns. If exposed to internet, it may allow your systems to be used as DoS attack amplifiers against other hosts. If you use `wsdd2`, you should block any traffic to ports 3702 and 5355 (UDP and TCP) at the border of your network, in both directions: you'll want neither untrusted WS-Discover messages to get in to your network, nor your own systems' WS-Discover messages to leak out.